# Bash script for mounting and backing up VeraCrypt volumes

Tags: bash, linux

My bash script mounts two VeraCrypt volumes, rsyncs their contents, and dismounts them. The script takes two parameters, the path for both the source and backup veracrypt volumes. I wrote this script so rsync wouldn't have to copy an entire volume if there was a single change in it.

This is my second time with bash scripting so please let me know what I could do better.

Thanks

````
#!/bin/bash

# Requirements:
# - Must have both veracrypt and rsync installed
# - Must be ran on Unix based systems
# - Both volumes must have the same password

function prepare_volumes_for_exit() {
    # dismount volumes
    veracrypt -d
    echo "Volumes dismounted"

    # delete mount points
    sudo rm -r "$source_mount_point"
    sudo rm -r "$backup_mount_point"
    echo "Mount points purged"
}

# removes double or single quotes from strings of they exist
function format_string() {
    if [ "${1:0:1}" == "'" ] && [ "${1: -1}" == "'" ]; then
        echo "${1:1:-1}"
    elif [ "${1:0:1}" == '"' ] && [ "${1: -1}" == '"' ]; then
        echo "${1:1:-1}"
    else
        echo "$1"

    fi
}

# make sure all volumes are removed before starting
veracrypt -d

# check that 2 params are passed
if ! [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Error: 2 parameters are required [source_volume_path] [backup_volume_path]"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Enter the password for the veracrypt volume: "
read -s veracrypt_password

# path to veracrypt volumes
source_volume_path="$(format_string "$1")"
backup_volume_path="$(format_string "$2")"

# generate random mount point
source_mount_point="$(format_string "/mnt/$(uuidgen)")"
backup_mount_point="$(format_string "/mnt/$(uuidgen)")"

# flag to determine if drives are mounted
source_volume_mounted=0
backup_volume_mounted=0

# create mount points
sudo mkdir -p "$source_mount_point"
sudo mkdir -p "$backup_mount_point"

echo "Beginning to mount volumes"
sudo veracrypt -t --mount "$source_volume_path" "$source_mount_point" -p "$veracrypt_password" --non-interactive

# checks that the source volume mounted
while read -r drive_number volume_location vc_mapper mount_location; do
    formatted_volume_location="$(format_string "$volume_location")"
    formatted_mount_location="$(format_string "$mount_location")"
    if [ "$formatted_volume_location" == "$source_volume_path" ] && [ "$formatted_mount_location" == "$source_mount_point" ]; then
        echo "Source volume mounted"
        source_volume_mounted=1
    else
        echo "Error: source volume not mounted"
        prepare_volumes_for_exit
        exit 1
    fi
done <<< $(veracrypt -t -l)

sudo veracrypt -t --mount "$backup_volume_path" "$backup_mount_point" -p "$veracrypt_password" --non-interactive

# checks both the source and backup volumes are mounted
# http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#source
while read -r drive_number volume_location vc_mapper mount_location; do
    formatted_volume_location="$(format_string "$volume_location")"
    formatted_mount_location="$(format_string "$mount_location")"
    if [ "$formatted_volume_location" == "$source_volume_path" ] && [ "$formatted_mount_location" == "$source_mount_point" ]; then
        source_volume_mounted=1
    elif [ "$formatted_volume_location" == "$backup_volume_path" ] && [ "$formatted_mount_location" == "$backup_mount_point" ]; then
        echo "Backup volume mounted"
        backup_volume_mounted=1
    else
        echo "Error: source or backup volume not mounted"
        prepare_volumes_for_exit
        exit 1
    fi
done <<< $(veracrypt -t -l)

if [ "$source_volume_mounted" -eq 1 ] && [ "$backup_volume_mounted" -eq 1 ]
then 
    echo "Volumes mounted, beginning rsync"
#    sudo rsync -hrtq --exclude-from='/media/miller/Primary/exclude.txt' --delete $source_mount_point/ $backup_mount_point
    echo "rsync complete"
else 
    echo 'Error: Drives were not mounted successfully, skipping rsync'
fi

prepare_volumes_for_exit

echo "Complete"
exit 0

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is a more portable [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588).
- `function prepare_volumes_for_exit()` can be simplified to `prepare_volumes_for_exit()`.
- Using `sudo` within a script is generally discouraged, since it makes it easy to do really bad things without explicit user consent. Instead, remove the `sudo`s and tell the user to run the whole script as root.
- `format_string` is an anti-pattern. First, because quotes are actually valid characters in paths, but more importantly because it is a strong indication that you're expecting the user to wrongly input broken strings.
- `! [ $# -eq 2 ]` can be simplified as `[ $# -ne 2 ]`.
- ```bsh
  while read -r drive_number volume_location vc_mapper mount_location
  …
  done <<< $(veracrypt -t -l)
  ```

  can be improved as

  ```
  while read -r -u9 drive_number volume_location vc_mapper mount_location
  …
  done 9< <(veracrypt -t -l)
  ```

  This way, no [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) happens on the input, and [commands within the `while` loop which happen to read from stdin won't break the loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#How_to_keep_other_commands_from_.22eating.22_the_input).
- `exit 0` is redundant.
- By convention, scripts should be silent if there is nothing important to report, and any error messages should go to standard error rather than standard output.